# read-event read entire arrow key instead of escape

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes, events

In graphical emacs on OS X, `(read-event)` in the scratch buffer produces `left`, however in iterm2 (which I configured to send `esc-*` for arrow keys), I get something like

```
(read-event)
27
OD
```

when I press the left arrow. Configuring iterm2 to use esc for arrow keys works well with the other programs I use and I am reluctant to change it. Is there another function I can use instead of read-event that will pick up the entire arrow key?

Comment: maybe `read-key`?

Comment: @npostavs Interesting. That works. How exactly do `read-key`, `read-char`, and `read-event` differ?

Comment: See [Elisp ref: Reading One Event](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-One-Event.html)